# SQL update using data collected by C# from Arduino Serial

Tags: c#, sql, serial-port, arduino, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to write a simple program in C# that will read data output from an Arduino connected via serial, lift the relevant data out of the text strings which are formatted for ease-of-understanding in the Serial Monitor, display the two pieces of information in two read-only text boxes that act as counters (overwrite every time the information is updated), and UPDATE an SQL table with these figures.

---

Example:

Arduino outputs:

```
'Day Users: 234231'
'All Users: 433241'
```

C# displays full message in textbox1

C# displays 234231 in textbox2

C# displays 433241 in textbox3

C# UPDATES SQL table with something like:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE USER_NUMBERS
SET NUMBERZ= 234231 
WHERE UPTIME = DAYHK");
```

But obviously, '234231' is a variable, specified by the input from the Arduino, which then informs the content of both textbox2 and the value needed to update the SQL table.

---

I'm very new to C#, but so far I have a program which can read the serial data from the Arduino and put the entire output into textbox1, but no more.

How can I specify a part of the incoming data that I want assigned to a value to be the text output in both textbox2 (or textbox3), and then use it to do both that and an update of the value held in my SQL table?

My code so far is thus:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Serial_Reader
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        string RxString;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM3";
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;

            serialPort1.Open();
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                buttonStart.Enabled = false;
                buttonStop.Enabled = true;
                buttonSQL.Enabled = true;
                textBox1.ReadOnly = false;
            }
        }

        private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.Close();
                buttonStart.Enabled = true;
                buttonStop.Enabled = false;
                buttonSQL.Enabled = false;
                textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            // If the port is closed, don't try to send a character.

            if (!serialPort1.IsOpen) return;

            // If the port is Open, declare a char[] array with one element.
            char[] buff = new char[1];

            // Load element 0 with the key character.

            buff[0] = e.KeyChar;

            // Send the one character buffer.
            serialPort1.Write(buff, 0, 1);

            // Set the KeyPress event as handled so the character won't
            // display locally. If you want it to display, omit the next line.
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen) serialPort1.Close();
        }

        private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(RxString);
        }

        private void buttonSQL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
 }
```

As you can see from 'my' adept commenting, but inept programming, I am using code from the brilliant tutorial [here](http://csharp.simpleserial.com): and all that my program will have extra is a button to begin the SQL communication, stopped when the Serial comms are stopped, and two extra textboxes.

---

**EDIT**:

The input is in the format:

```
Someone got up from seat number 9
All-time users on seat number 9 is: 5
Today's total users: 17
All-time total users: 17
```

So that non-programmers checking the serial monitor can easily understand the output. The first line is always either 'Someone got up from' or 'Someone sat down on', on the second line, only the numbers change, and again on the third and fourth lines, but the numbers on the third and fourth lines (in this case the same because the system has been running less than a day) are the ones that need to be parsed.

---

**EDIT 2** (New Code):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Serial_Reader
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        string RxString;

        public Form1()
        {
              InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM3";
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;

            serialPort1.Open();
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                buttonStart.Enabled = false;
                buttonStop.Enabled = true;
                buttonSQL.Enabled = true;
                textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }

        private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
            {
                serialPort1.Close();
                buttonStart.Enabled = true;
                buttonStop.Enabled = false;
                buttonSQL.Enabled = false;
                textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
            }
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            // If the port is closed, don't try to send a character.

            if (!serialPort1.IsOpen) return;

            // If the port is Open, declare a char[] array with one element.
            char[] buff = new char[1];

            // Load element 0 with the key character.

            buff[0] = e.KeyChar;

            // Send the one character buffer.
            serialPort1.Write(buff, 0, 1);

            // Set the KeyPress event as handled so the character won't
            // display locally. If you want it to display, omit the next line.
            e.Handled = true;
        }

        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));


        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (serialPort1.IsOpen) serialPort1.Close();
        }

        private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(RxString);

        }

        private void buttonSQL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //   SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("user id=username;" +
            //                            "password=password;server=serverurl;" +
            //                            "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
            //                            "database=database; " +
            //                            "connection timeout=30");

            do
            {
                string dayUsers, allUsers;
                string s1 = "Today's total users: ";
                string s2 = "All-time total users: ";

                if (RxString.Contains(s1))
                {
                dayUsers = RxString.Replace(s1, "");
                textDU.Text = dayUsers;
           //     string queryDay = "UPDATE USER_NUMBERS SET NUMBERZ=" + dayUsers + "WHERE UPTIME=DAYHK";
                }

                if (RxString.Contains(s2))
                {
                allUsers = RxString.Replace(s2, "");
                textAU.Text = allUsers;
           //     string queryAll = "UPDATE USER_NUMBERS SET NUMBERZ=" + allUsers + "WHERE UPTIME=ALLHK";
                }
            }
            while (serialPort1.IsOpen);
        }



        private void textDU_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textAU_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

---

**EDIT 3** (Incoming Data):

```
if (abs (then [i] - now[i]) > THRESH)
{
  Serial.print ("Someone ");
  if (now [i] > then [i])
  {
    Serial.print ("sat on");
    allusers++;
    dayusers++;
    digitalWrite(counterPin, HIGH);  // hit counter
    delay(75);
    digitalWrite(counterPin, LOW);
    val[i]++;
  }  
  else
  {
    Serial.print ("got up from");
  }  
  Serial.print (" seat number ");
  Serial.println (i);
  Serial.print ("All-time users on seat number ");
  Serial.print (i);
  Serial.print (" is: ");
  Serial.println (val[i]); 
  Serial.print ("Today's total users: ");
  Serial.println (dayusers);
  Serial.print ("All-time total users: ");
  Serial.println (allusers);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that the input string is always in the same format, and that the numbers always have 6 digits, you may use simple substrings:

```
int dayUsers, allUsers;
Int32.TryParse(RxString.Substring(12, 6), out dayUsers);
Int32.TryParse(RxString.Substring(32, 6), out allUsers);
```

Otherwise you could make the parsing a little bit more sophisticated:

```
int dayUsers, allUsers;
string[] parts = RxString.Split('\'', ':');
if (parts.Length > 5)
{
    Int32.TryParse(parts[2].Trim(), out dayUsers);
    Int32.TryParse(parts[5].Trim(), out allUsers);
}
```

Then it's just a matter of using the numbers in the text boxes and SQL query:

```
textBox2.Text = dayUsers.ToString();
textBox3.Text = allUsers.ToString();

string query = "UPDATE USER_NUMBERS SET NUMBERZ=" + dayUsers + "WHERE UPTIME=DAYHK"
```

**EDIT:**
Given that the four lines of data is available in textBox1, you may use something like this to extract the strings containing the numbers:

```
string[] inputLines = textBox1.Text.Split('\n');
if (inputLines.Length == 4)
{
    string dayUsers = inputLines[2].Substring(inputLines[2].IndexOf(':') + 1).Trim();
    string allUsers = inputLines[3].Substring(inputLines[3].IndexOf(':') + 1).Trim();
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
Suggestion for code parsing possibly incomplete data in TextBox1:

```
private void buttonSQL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get unsaved input from text box
    string input = textBox1.Text;
    string[] inputLines = input.Split('\n');

    // Find and process relevant input
    foreach(string line in inputLines)
    {
        if (line.EndsWith("\r")) // Make sure line is complete
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("Today's total users: "))
            {
                string dayUsers = line.Substring(20).Trim();
                textDU.Text = dayUsers;
                // SQL query...
            }
            else if (line.StartsWith("All-time total users: "))
            {
                string allUsers = line.Substring(21).Trim();
                textAU.Text = allUsers;
                // SQL query...
            }
        }
    }

    // Only keep unparsed text in text box
    textBox1.Text = inputLines[inputLines.Length - 1];
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your speedy response. I've edited the original post to explain a little about the incoming data. Looking at your code and having read a little about Int32.TryParse since posting, this seems to make perfect sense, I just need a little help on the specifics, if you wouldn't mind? Where are you getting the numbers 2 and 5 from? The numbers being input won't always be six digit numbers, but they won't ever be more than six digits...

Comment: Hi, the 2 and 5 came from the assumption that the input was in the format: "'Day Users: 234231'\n'All Users: 433241'". Splitting that string with the characters ' and : would create 7 parts, where the third and sixth (zero-based index 2 and 5) would contain the numbers, see the documentation of String.Split() and String.Trim(). Given the new information, it would probably be cleanest to first split the string into lines using `RxString.Split('\n')`, and then split the the 3rd and 4th line individually to obtain the numbers in the second part: `part[2].Split(':')` and `part[3].Split(':')`.

Comment: Hello again, and thank you, I had a go with both Split and Trim, but I couldn't get it to work - when using split, are you left with two strings, one either side of the character? I edited the original post to save horrendous formatting of the code I've come up with instead... which still doesn't work. When using `Split('\n')`, I was getting an error thrown because there weren't enough `parts` in the array, supposedly, is it somehow not interpreting the line breaks correctly?

Character limit reached >>

Comment: (continued)

The code above uses `Contains` and `Replace` to select and trim the right part of the `RxString` and assign it, but now it just hangs with a `NullReferenceException`. Is it my syntax that's wrong?

Comment: Where do you get the NullReferenceException? The only null candidates I can see right now is RxString, textAU, textDU and serialPort1. None of them should be null, given that any text has been received. Check for the line number or call stack in the exception. 
Split('\n') splits the string on line breaks. I assumed that all four lines were always received at once, but that might not be true. When the SQL button is pressed, it's probably better to use the content of textBox1 instead of RxString, and then apply Split etc to that string. I'll edit my reply to clarify.

Comment: I think perhaps the issues are arising because of the way the data are arriving from the Arduino itself; it's not simply printing lines, or even a block, but I'm unsure why, when I add the code you mentioned above, meaning that it's now taking its values from the textbox, it doesn't work. Is it still not four strings/one string? On the plus side, the application doesn't hang any more, it just doesn't do anything visible.

Call stack simply highlights the following line in Serial_Reader.Program: `Application.Run(new Form1());`

Comment: Since there are some uncertainties about the input data, I think you should set breakpoints, and in the debugger check the actual string value of textBox1.Text and check if it contains the expected number of new line characters. Maybe you should change to `inputLines.Length == 4`. I'm guessing here, but I think with some stepping in the debugger you should see what's wrong

Comment: Debugging textbox1.Text shows that the its Value ends up something like  `"eone sat on seat number 11\r\nAll-time users on seat number 11 is: 15\r\nToday's total users: 78\r\nAll-time total users: 78\r\nSomeone sat on se" `, in other words, since it's appending, it's all one string, so does it seem sensible to think that the original method of splitting by '\n' might work, potentially using '\r\n' for the CR, but fiddling with code as it doesn't **really** come through in nice little sets of four..? Any ideas? I feel painfully close, thanks for your help already.

Comment: So it seems it is now a matter of handling incomplete input data in textBox1. I added a suggestion for that in Edit 2. I guess it is necessary to do check against the expected strings in each complete row and parse the value from there. It is important to keep any unfinished line in the text box to be able to parse it later.

Comment: Aha! Much more elegant, please ignore the last post, I'll now delete it. Are the 20 and 21 the number of characters in the required string? I only ask because if they are they don't count the whitespace at the end of the string. Is this correct? I'll give it a try now, nonetheless, thanks!

Comment: 20 and 21 are the start index of Substring, they refer to the first character after the colon (space). Both that space and any trailing spaces and \r are removed bu Trim().

Comment: Holy wow. Beautiful. I commented out the last line and it still works, but I'm going to go with your way, as otherwise the textbox will fill up fairly rapidly. I also moved the segment to the `private void DisplayText` so that it keeps it updated without a button press - I changed my mind about that. Thank you so much @ekholm !